# What form of the verb is used with the word "did" (especially in a interrogative sentence)

Tags: tense, verb-forms

> Jill **did not allow** last game to Liz.

Or

> Jill **did not allowed** last game to Liz.

Do we always use the infinitive form of the verb with "did"?

Comment: The auxiliary verb "do" **obligatorily** requires the verb that follows it to be an infinitive; in this case 'allow'. "Did" is the past tense of the verb "do", so the reference to past time is clear. Btw, is there a reason why you have omitted the determiner 'the' before 'last'?

Answer (score 2):

The use of *did* instead of *do* already marks the sentence as being in the past, so the main verb doesn't need changing and stays in its base form.

Answer (score -1):

You have use simple present verb with did.You can't use past/past participle verb with 'did'.As example 'I did go'

Comment: Sorry, but that's incorrect. The auxiliary verb "do" obligatorily requires the verb that follows it to be an infinitive; in this case 'allow'. That is not the simple present, though it is spelled the same.